# Can Versatile Spellcaster be used multiple times at once?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

One of the players in our campaign plays a level 6 favored soul. They have selected Versatile Spellcaster as their next feat; it reads

> You can use two spell slots of the same level to cast a spell you know that is one level higher. For example, a sorcerer with this feat can expend two 2nd-level spell slots to cast any 3rd-level spell [they know]. (*Races of the Dragon* 101)

Does this effect chain? In other words, could the Favored Soul expend…

```
((Lv0 + Lv0 -> Lv1) + Lv1 -> Lv2) + Lv2 -> Lv3
```

…to gain a 3rd-level spell? It would expend two 0-level, 1 1st-level, and one 2nd-level spell, but would be extremely powerful at higher levels.

How does this work, and is this an acceptable use of teh feat Versatile Spellcaster? If so, are there any balance concerns to be aware of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, Versatile Spellcaster does not "chain" in this way.

There is not much in the way of rules text for this feat, but part of it is that the character uses *two spell slots* to *cast a spell*.

The thing that makes chaining impossible is that there is a difference between having a spell slot and casting a spell. Versatile Spellcaster only grants the latter, not a spell slot that can be used to fuel another use of the feat.

There are quite a few interesting and supremely powerful things this feat can do, but chaining is not one of them.